# How to append Two different ID on a TAG

Tags: javascript

I want to append two different ids in my table and show the IDs result in Console Log when I click the button of table `<tr>`:

**MY CODE:**

```
var id1 = snap.child("id").val();
var id2 = snap.child("idPaciente").val();
$("#tbl").append("<tr data-id1='"+id+"' data-id2='"+id2+"'><td>"
  + nome + "</td><td>"
  + apelido + "</td><td>"
  + mensagem + "</td><td>"
  + "<button type='button' id='btn'>Responder</button></td></tr>");

  $("#tbl").on('click', '#btn', function (e) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'), rowId1 = $row.data('id1'), rowId2 = $row.data('id2');
    var rowId1 = $row.data('id1');
    var rowId2 = $row.data('id2');

    console.log("ID1: " + rowId);
    console.log("ID2: " + rowId2);

});
```

**My console.log result:**

```
ID1: -LtUdCRBBuUgIRzkrN48
ID2: undefined
```

Comment: What is `snap`? How do you know that `id2` wasn't `undefined` to begin with?

Comment: If you mean a HTML attribute `id` then it's not valid to do so. An id must not contain white space so there is no way to separate values.

Comment: not possible to have two ids in one html tag. You may be looking for custom data attributes. e.g: <tag data-attribute-1="data" data-attribute-2="data2" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues

1. You kept forgetting the 1 on id1
2. You need to use class on the button, not ID
3. you have two unnecessary lines

I assume firebase so I pretend I have snap.

Change the first lines back to

```
var id1 = snap.child("id").val(), id2 = snap.child("idPaciente").val();
```

when you are happy with my code

```js
/* For testing */

// var id1 = snap.child("id").val(), id2 = snap.child("idPaciente").val(); 


var snap = null;
var id1 = snap ? snap.child("id").val() : "x",
  id2 = snap ? snap.child("idPaciente").val() : "y"
  
var nome = "Name 1",  apelido = "Bla", mensagem = "bla bla"

/* end testing */

$("#tbl").append("<tr data-id1='" + id1 /* TYPO */ + "' data-id2='" + id2 + "'><td>" +
  nome + "</td><td>" +
  apelido + "</td><td>" +
  mensagem + "</td><td>" +
  "<button type='button' class='btn'>Responder</button></td></tr>");

$("#tbl").on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
    rowId1 = $row.data('id1'), // TYPO
    rowId2 = $row.data('id2');
  // var rowId1 = $row.data('id1'); // not needed
  // var rowId2 = $row.data('id2'); // not needed

  console.log("ID1: " + rowId1); // TYPO
  console.log("ID2: " + rowId2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tbl"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you very much, you saved me, it's working perfectly.

Comment: You had two more unnecessary lines. See updated